# Can I use Applescript in Automator to remember/recall variables and folder locations?

Tags: applescript, automator, memory

I am a total noob when it comes to using Automator (so late to the party), but I'm trying to create an app that imports, renames, resizes, and duplicates images.

I've already created a workflow that does all of this, but I'd like for the user to be able to input certain variables **only the first time** they use the app, and then have the app *draw on those variables* for subsequent uses.

Is there perhaps a way to do this with Applescript? (noob with Applescript too)

Below is a simple example of what I'd like to do, however I'd like to set up multiple "remembered" variables.

Example:

1st run

1. Choose file destination [result=Import folder]
2. Choose images to be imported

2nd (and later) run

(remembers destination as Import folder, doesn't ask for this input)
1. Choose images to be imported

Since I'm new to all of this, I have this idea that maybe I could build one app (only to be used to set up the variables) that would create a text file with all of the relevant variable info, and then the second app could "read" this file. I have no idea how to do this though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: Put them in files and then read them back ?

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm not sure what you mean by that...

Comment: On the first run, put all the variables in a text file & on subsequent runs, verify that the file is not empty and then load the variables from there. Think of how cache works for say youtube. They put some info in some files in your browser & later read them

Comment: Oh I just saw that it is in your question. See "text" in library & you can find several things for opening a new textedit document, setting contents of textedit document & later get contents of the document. use the "variables" feature of automator for text passing etc.

Comment: Great, thanks so much!! I'll look into doing this!!